# Erro ao inserir Dataframe Pandas na base de dados MySQL com a função to.sql()

Tags: mysql, python, pandas

**Ao tentar executar este código:**

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('arquivo.csv',
                 sep=",",
                 encoding="ANSI",
                 low_memory=False)

config = {
    'host': "localhost",
    'user': "root",
    'password': "senha",
    'database': "database",
    'raise_on_warnings': True
}
with mysql.connector.connect(**config) as conn:
    df.to_sql(
        name='tabelabd',
        con=conn,
        if_exists='append',
        index=False)
```

**Tenho este erro:**

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE
> type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL
> statement

O banco de dados e a tabela estão criados, o tipo de dados do df e da coluna da tabela do bd é o mesmo, a conexão é realizada, quando faço um insert manualmente funciona normal, porém, quando uso o to_sql aparece este erro de sqlite, mas estou usando o MySQL

Uma coisa que pensei é que a sintaxe utilizada pela função to_sql seja destina ao sqlite e quanto tento utilizar no MySQL da erro, mas é só um palpite.

Também já tentei utilizar o driver pymsql mas dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Eu diria que você possui mais colunas no `df` do que na tabela. Mas, é só um palpite, pois você não postou o `csv` nem a definição da tabela. Outra possibilidade é que você não usou o parâmetro `method` que provavelmente tem que ser igual a `multi` pois vc tenta inserir mais de uma linha do seu df.

Comment: A base csv tem apenas uma coluna com o título e abaixo os valores todos inteiros.   O código de criação de base é esse                                                                                DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS teste;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS teste;
USE teste;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS codigo;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS codigo(
    cod_Predio INT NOT NULL

) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;                                                                  Inseri o parâmetro method='Multi', mas, infelizmente, também não funcionou.

Comment: Baseado na documentação, a conexão **TEM** que ser do tipo `sqlalchemy (engine or connection)`. Dá uma olhada na [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Baseado na documentação, a conexão TEM que ser do tipo sqlalchemy
> (engine or connection). Dá uma olhada na doc – Paulo Marques

Perfeito, essa resposta do Paulo Marques resolveu o problema, utilizei a conexão do tipo sqlalchemy e o comando do pandas df.to_sql funcionou perfeitamente.

Muito obrigado.